# iOS Binding : How to create a binding for a class that implements several delegates?

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to make a binding project, but I don't know how to bind the next interface, which implements three different delegates:

```
@interface Integration :  NSObject<NSURLConnectionDelegate, SomeControllerDelegate, 
CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    id<VendorIntegrationDelegate> delegate;
    Information *Information;
    SomeController * controller;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign) id<VendorIntegrationDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic,strong) Information *Information;
@property(nonatomic,strong) SomeController *controller;

@end
```

In the ApiDefinition.cs I have made the binding as follows, which lacks the implementation of SomeControllerDelegate and CLLocationManagerDelegate:

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSUrlConnectionDelegate), Delegates=new string [] { "WeakDelegate" },
Events=new Type [] { typeof (VendorIntegrationDelegate)})]
public partial interface Integration
{
    [Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Assign), NullAllowed]
    NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }

    [Wrap("WeakDelegate")]
    VendorIntegrationDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

    [Export ("Information", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    Information Information { get; set; }

    [Export ("controller", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
    SomeController  Controller { get; set; }

}
```

The problem that I found while making this binding is that the interface inherits from several classes, how to create this binding

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about `SomeControllerDelegate`, you declare it as `[Model]` and without `[BaseType]` like this:

```cs
[Model]
interface SomeControllerDelegate
{
    //...
}

//...

[BaseType (typeof (NSUrlConnectionDelegate), /*...*/]
interface Integration : SomecontrollerDelegate
{
    ...
}
```